# Amperage on brushed motors

Tags: motor

I am currently building a hobby-weight (5.44kg) robot and will be using 2 x 14.4 cordless driller motors for my wheels.

The thing is I keep reading about high amperages when working with r/c models such as quadcopters BUT when I connect my cordless driller motor to my bench power supply and monitor current draw it never rises above 3.2 Amps even when I try to stop the motor by hand.

Of course in the arena in the event of a stand off I have plastic wheels which will slip so I am not too concerned about stall currents.

I am now left wondering whether I have mis-calculated or whether people make a lot of fuss about high currents for nothing. or do these currents only perhaps really apply to brush-less motors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stall amps are dependent on your type of motor, there are motors with stall currents into the 100's of amps, and some into a few milli amps. 3.2 Amps isn't a lot, but it isn't impossibly little either. The motor's used by quadcopters are brushless, they generally are way higher powered, into hundreds of watt's and more.

Make sure your power supply isn't current limited to 3.2 A. You are probably fine with a motor driver capable of something like 4A.